# Formatting of captions with memoir

Tags: captions, memoir, hyphenation

This is my first question here. I have been reading very useful answers for years. Now, I did not find one that solves my problem.

I am typestting a book with the **memoir** class, and I am finding the following issue with figures' and tables' **caption**s: When the caption is more than one line long, the caption's text is typeset right-justified, and very often without any hyphenation, which may result in a very wide blank space between the caption's name+number and the real text, plus too much horizontal spacing in the caption's lines. Even when in some cases there is some hyphenation, I also get a wide blank space after name+number.

I tried to set several parameters (`\captionstyle`, `\captionwidth`), I have also added discretionary hyphens `\-`, but the problem, in slightly different ways, seems to persist. Even when the blank after name+number seems wider than the unhyphenated word, and when I put `\captionstyle{raggedrigth}`, LaTeX insists in putting a wide blank after name+number.

Is this a kown issue ? Should I use the **caption package** ?

Comment: Memoir incorporates the functionality of the `caption` package, so you should be able to use Memoir's commands alone.

Comment: @AndrewCashner Not quite true, the caption package can do much more that what the memoir interface offers.

Answer (score 4):

The caption styles are describe on section 10.5, page 183 in Memoir manual. It enable powerful formatting of caption appearance.

I use the following (quite nonstandard) caption style:

```
\captiondelim{\null\newline}
\captionnamefont{\small\sffamily\bfseries}
\captiontitlefont{\small\sffamily\linespread{.84}\selectfont}
\captionstyle[\raggedright]{}
\normalcaptionwidth
\captiontitlefinal{.}
\setlength\belowcaptionskip{.5ex}
```

For more particular answer you need to provide Minimal Working Example, which will show, what is your problem.

Answer (score 0):

PROBLEM SOLVED ... side effect of another (badly executed) hack ... !!!

The problem was very strange. Besides it, I had also noticed that my **headlines** had become right shifted ... so I began to revise what had I done *just before* getting into the problem ... weak memory (over sixty) ... but finally I got it: I wanted to change the `\abovedisplayskip` value for displayed formulas and the like. This you have to do by modifying `\normalsize` and `\small`, which I did by using **memoir**'s great `\addtodef` facility ... so far, so good, great displayed formulas ... but the way I did this introduced four unwanted and non-cancellable spaces in front of the text every time the macros `\normalsize` and `\small` were called, and this was the case in every `\caption` and in the headlines, which are set in `\small` size ...

I added `%` at the appropriate places (ends of macros before breaking lines of code) and now everythings works as desired.

Thanks, zarko, for your interest.